# CoreData foreign keys/relationship to same table

Tags: swift, core-data, database-design

I can’t work out how to model the following in CoreData with swift as it doesn’t seem as simple as it would be in SQL. I want a foreign key table in the middle of two tables eg,

**Projects**
Id,
Name

**Resource**
Id,
Name

**SharedResource**
Project1_id,
Project2_id,
Resource_id

So this SharedResource entity I can’t work out using the CoreData relationships - would it be a new table with three 1:1 relationships? Or am I completely off track?

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

A new entity (Core Data doesn't say "table") with three relationships is one way to do it. That would look something like this.

[image: SharedResource with 3 relationships]

The main disadvantage is that you can't change to a different number of projects on `SharedResource` (should that need ever occur) without updating the data model.

A different way would be to use two relationships, with the `SharedResource` -> `Projects` relationship as a to-many relationship, like this:

[image: SharedResource with to-many relationship]

That's flexible in that it can allow any number of `Projects` for a single `SharedResource`. However if you really need to limit it to 2, you'd need to either set a max count in the data model (so that Core Data could verify the limit when you save changes) or else write code to enforce the limit.